# Why is SVG textPath not rendering? [0x0 in devtools]

Tags: css, vue.js, svg, gridsome

I copied this snippet from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath) into a **Vue component**.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id="MyPath" fill="none" stroke="red"
        d="M10,90 Q90,90 90,45 Q90,10 50,10 Q10,10 10,40 Q10,70 45,70 Q70,70 75,50" />
  <text>
    <textPath href="#MyPath">
      Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
    </textPath>
  </text>

</svg>
```

However the `<textPath>` doesn't show up, only the `<path>` renders.

I tried setting explicit width, display, overflow etc. but to no avail. Its' width & height stay 0x0.

This stumps me, as the same snippet works in other tabs when not using Vue.

Just to clarify: I'm using **Vue** & **Gridsome**.

Comment: Cannot reproduce - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/pooYGRr

Comment: @Paulie_D As I wrote, this issue is only happening in a Vue component.

Comment: Then you'd have to demo it I'd suggest.

Comment: Appears to work fine in Vue component: https://jsfiddle.net/uv10f6ap/1/

Comment: Could be a gridsome related issue

Answer (score 1):

After an hour debugging, I found the cause to the issue: When the `body` has a `dir="rtl"` the text doesn't render.

All I had to do was reset the SVG's direction to `ltr`.

But how can I have it work in `rtl`???

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849981/rendering-rtl-text-along-an-svg-path), no answer.